# Why are layers not lining up with others with the same CRS?

Tags: qgis, vector, coordinate-system

I am creating a project on the UK and have downloaded various shapefiles. When I add a vector layer they are coming up as if they are not lining up. Some layers are nicely on top of each other with WRC84 and the others appear to be angled off and are away somewhere else and all have the same CRS....

what do i do?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Quantum GIS 1.7.4

Comment: This is a projection issue. The shapefiles are in different coordinate systems.  They may be miss-labeled.

Comment: Are you sure that the shapefiles are in the same CRS? Check the download page for info about it.
Are you sure that in the QGIS project they are set with the same CRS? Select all layers with Ctrl+leftclick, then right click > set CRS.

Comment: closed since the OP did not answer necessary clarifying questions.

Answer (score 1):

Check the properties of the shapefiles that are not lining up against those that do. 
Try to begin a new project file with the 'bad' layer first.  Check its location before any other layers are inserted.  Review the properties of each additional layer as you add them to try and determine which is affecting the other.