# Why the georeferencing in UTM does not work with the QGIS georeferencer?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

First time here, sorry if this looks simple.

I use QGIS on Windows 7. I georeferenced a toposheet with geographic references to UTM. When I superimpose a UTM raster, the toposheet is near the origin and the rater far away but properly imported.

I then georeferenced the toposheet with its system and warped it to UTM and it worked, the two rasters are properly superimposed. Can someone explain why the georeferencing in UTM does not work the first time with the georeferencer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are layers not lining up with others with the same CRS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24005/why-are-layers-not-lining-up-with-others-with-the-same-crs)

Comment: *I georeferenced a toposheet with geographic references to UTM.* Sorry, I don't understand what this means. That you used geographic (lat/lon) control points when georeferencing?