# Why are layers not overlapping to each other inspite of having same CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am new to QGIS and working with QGIS 1.7.3 version, I have my all layers in WGS 84 CRS but even though they are not overlapping to each other, What should I do ?

Comment: same problem as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24005/why-are-layers-not-lining-up-with-others-with-the-same-crs?rq=1

Comment: What's the magnitude of the shift between the layers? Just a few metres or thousands of kilometers?

Comment: This is *the* GIS FAQ: everybody has this problem at some point. But for the question to be answerable, details are needed concerning the CRSes, the datasets, and the procedures that have been followed.  As they have not been forthcoming, I vote to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

My first guess would be that the spatial references are not correct or may be missing. If you have a layer that you know is correct (i.e. other layers overlap) then take an incorrect layer and try to reproject using the coordinate system from a correct layer. [This walk-through may be of some use to you](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/04/tutorial-working-with-projections-in.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, but I tried a lot, most importantly there is shift between the layers of thousands kilometers and these are vector layer not raster. How can I reproject vector layer. All layers have spatial reference and that is correct and if I overlap incorrect layer it also shows CRS in its properties, and if I opened this incorrect vector layer in ARCGIS it doen't show any spatial refernce. I assigned spatial refence in Arc Catalog, instead of doing this the layers are not overlapping. What to do ? please answer

Comment: I am guessing you are seeing a CRS in ArcMap because it is picking up the CRS of the data frame, which is automatically assigned to the CRS of whatever the first layer you add to the map is. Try adding the incorrect layer to the map and tell me what the CRS is. You can project a vector in the data management -> project -> feature